# Why is the "User Defined..." button for ActiveX disabled in QTP's Object Identification dialog?

Tags: qtp, functional-testing

[image]

I wonder why the button shown in the screenshot is disabled.

Background:

We tested the Flight Application in QTP. Its ActiveX Object is recognized as a WinObject. So obviously, ActiveX support is disabled. How do I solve this?

ActiveX option is checked.

[image]

while recording, Tools->Object identification option is disabled.

[image]

Still not working.

Comment: While recording you can't change the object identification settings. You should stop recording and then change the settings. Anyway this is a different question. Please don't mix questions it confuses things

Answer (score 2):

This button has nothing to do with not recognising ActiveX controls. Make sure of the following

1. You have selected the ActiveX addin when loading QTP
2. In the *Record & Run Settings* either you select *record and run on all applications* or you specifically add the application you're testing (flight).

Comment: I add Object in Object Repository in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424305/why-cant-user-defined-button-disabled-in-qtp-in-activex-environment

Comment: I have added ActiveX object through Object Repository dialog. While writing script manually, ActiveX object was assumed as a Winobject.  How to solve this issue?

Comment: kindly see the above Images.

Comment: + 1 because it´s true. Sorry for duplicating your answer, I did not understand your post correctly at first, and after my own research, I got the point.

Answer (score 0):

**You probably have not activated the ActiveX add-in.**

Enable the add-in manager ("Show add-in manager on startup" in tools, options), and there, check the associated checkbox when you re-open QTP.

Update: The "User-defined..." button is always gray except for when you select "Standard Windows" in the "Environment:" dropdown (in the Object Identification Dialog). This is by design, and documented. Online help of that dialog says:

> User-Defined -- Enables you to map an unidentified or custom class to
>   a standard Windows class by opening the Object Mapping Dialog Box.
>
> Note: To enable this option, you must select the Standard Windows
>   environment from the Environment list.

Strange that this coin dropped so late (as one would say in German) :-)

Update 2: and as I see now, this is exactly what Motti says in his answer, so I´d suggest you accept his´, not mine.

Comment: we Enable the add-in manager Properly and restart QTP and again I have added ActiveX object through Object Repository dialog. While writing script manually, ActiveX object was assumed as a Winobject.  How to solve this issue?

Comment: Re-record! And even then, activex support might not record what you'd expect.

Comment: kindly see the above images.

Comment: On the second shot, you are currently recording. I think then the object identification menu item is rightfully disabled.